# What does "For" mean in the sentence "could you come down here for a second?"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Ok, "For" has [several meanings](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/for_1?q=for)

> -**used to show purpose or function**
>
> a machine for slicing bread
>
> Let's go for a walk.
>
> Are you learning English for pleasure or for your work?
>
> What did you do that for (= Why did you do that)?
>
> -**used to show a length of time**
>
> I'm going away for a few days.
>
> That's all the news there is for now.

Now see this sentence "**could you come down here for a second?**"

I guess "**For**" here means "**reason**"

I would say "**could you come down here for a second?**" could mean "**could you come down here for a short conversation with me?**"

Or does it means "**your coming action lasts a short time, not long**""?

Answer (score 1):

Your second guess is correct; it means "for a length of time".  The meaning of the sentence is something like "Could you come down here **for a brief span of time**?"

You are right that it can be a little ambiguous, because we use *for* to mean two different things.  If the sentence was "Could you come down here **for my birthday party**?" it would obviously mean "for the purpose of my birthday party."  But *a second* is a span of time, not a reason to do something.

Comment: I think they omitted "verb", "**Could you come down here for a second?**"="**Could you come down here to talk with me for a second?**" & "**for a second**" modifies "**talk**". It means "**talk with me for a very short time**"

Comment: @Tom - There's no verb missing from the original sentence, and no particular purpose is implied.  The speaker could mean "Could you come down here to talk with me for a second", but he could also mean "Could you come down here so we can see your haircut for a second" or "so you can see this TV commercial" or anything.  *for a second* does not specifically modify "talk" or any other verb, it modifies the entire preceding phrase.